# Align Text and Icon in one line

Tags: html, css

How can I align `Logout` and `logout.svg` in one line so that when you hover over it it gets displayed correctly?

```css
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#row {
    display: flex;
}
#logout {
    height: 25px;
}
#element {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #caced1;
}
#element:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div id="row">
        <img id="logout" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/135250/logout.svg">
        <span id="element">Logout</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to position the icon as absolute and add margin to it but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `align-items: center;`

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logout {
  height: 25px;
}

#element {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #caced1;
}

#element:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="row">
    <img id="logout" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/135250/logout.svg">
    <span id="element">Logout</span>
  </div>
</div>
```